# Getting Download failed. cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds

Tags: errors, curl

I'm trying to install some external plugins that came with my theme and I can't see to find a way to get the communication to work properly. I also have this issue being reported when trying to start a scan in Wordfence. Likewise, I am using Cyberpanel and Open Litespeed. Furthermore, I own the server, so I can make changes there both in the firewall and well as the configurations. If anyone could help me with this issue it would be amazing!

Comment: It's probably simplest to download and install the plugins manually I'd guess. Do the logs tell you which URL it was trying to download? You could add logging for that.

Comment: Although I'd expect if your system is firewalling off outbound connections you'd get connation failures, not timeouts.